API PLATFORM 3 - XML Mapping Open API
I work on API Platform 3 with Symfony 7. I try to map all entry-points with XML but I can't find a good documentation for the XML. I had to map it in XML because all of my entities are mapped in XML.
My following code below works perfectly but I can't change the parameters (default : "id") or the request body.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources xmlns="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/resources-3.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/resources-3.0 https://api-platform.com/schema/metadata/resources-3.0.xsd">
    <resource class="App\Entity\SomeEntity">
        <operations>
            <operation name="some_methode" class="ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection" controller="App\Controller\SomeController::someMethod" uriTemplate="/entrypoint/{name}" read="false" output="false">
                <requirements>
                    <requirement property="name">[a-zA-Z0-9]+</requirement>
                </requirements>
                <openapiContext>
                    <values>
                        <value name="summary">A summary</value>
                        <value name="description">Retrieve a of somethings.</value>
                    </values>
                </openapiContext>
            </operation>
        </operations>
    </resource>
</resources>

The only things I got "correctly" is this I just try with symfony error to make something.
<parameters>
    <parameter name="name" in="path" allowEmptyValue="false" allowReserved="false" explode="false" description="somedesc" required="true" deprecated="false">
        <schema>
            <values>
                <value></value>
            </values>
        </schema>
    </parameter>
</parameters>

